# How to reverse a @keyframe animation on mouse off?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I need to reverse the wipe animation when the mouse moves off the button. Is there a way to do this in only CSS?

I know I can reverse the animation, but I'm not sure where to put in the CSS file in order to get the right animation. If I put it in `.get-started`, it wipes the border and I'm unable to interact with the button completely.

HTML:

```
<div class="get-started" id="button">
      <h4 class="part1">Get <span class="part2">Started</span></h4>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {

  background:black;

}

#button {

    display: flex;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: white;

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  width: 250px;
  height: 75px;

    position: relative;
    top: -30%;
    left: calc(50% - 125px);

}

.get-started {
  --borderWidth: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: var(--borderWidth);
    background-color: #8551FF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px white;
    z-index:1;
}

.get-started h4.part1 {

    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Coves Light';
    font-weight: normal;

}

.get-started span.part2 {

    color: #5EFF00;
    font-family: 'Coves';
    font-weight: bold;

}

.get-started:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.get-started:hover:after {
    background: linear-gradient(60deg, #f79533, #f37055, #ef4e7b, #a166ab, #5073b8, #1098ad, #07b39b, #6fba82);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-size: 300% 300%;
    animation: frame-enter 1s forwards ease-in-out reverse, gradient-animation 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

/* motion */
@keyframes gradient-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 15% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 85% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 15% 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes frame-enter {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), 5px calc(100% - 5px), 5px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  25% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px) 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}
```

[Runnable Snippet](https://codepen.io/dish_uwu/pen/eYYBeoz)

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
.get-started:not(:hover):after {}
```

with an inversed animation. But it can have unwanted behaviour on initial pageload, it always starts with this animation I guess. Sometimes you can't avoid javascript. Adding a class on mouseout and removing it again on mouseenter might work, so you can assign a reverse animation to this class.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.get-started');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
        e.target.classList.add('mouseleaveAnimationClass');
    });
    els[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
        e.target.classList.remove('mouseleaveAnimationClass');
    });
}
```

Comment: How would I add the animation to a JS class? I'm a bit new to web development in general so I'm a bit lost. Thanks in advance!